# Long running Plone operation with AJAX progress bar

Tags: ajax, progress-bar, plone

I'd like to run tasks in Plone which take long time to complete (minutes). For the duration of the task I could present a progress bar using AJAX.

Are there any ready Plone libraries / add-ons which allow you to serialize task to pieces and give AJAX status report automatically, without need to manually split and maintain the long running task state on the server?

E.g.

- You start the task with start() method
- Task gives status with getStatus() or similar
- Framework will handle making the task asynchronous and has front-end code to follow the task status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[netsight.async](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/netsight.async) can do this.

Comment: that is great. I never heard of that product.