# Plone plugin, web interface development for commandline programs

Tags: python, content-management-system, plone, zope

I am considering to write a plugin/module for one of any of wellknown CMSes like Joomla, Drupal and Plone. I am very impressed with the clarity of many Plone-based sites, and excited with many praises people gave to Plone. Besides, I love Python also. So, I want to give Plone a try. Here a some information about the plugin I want to develop:

I have some Linux commandline programs that I want to run from within the CMS environment via this plugin. The plugin then save command output, run log to the user who runs the programs. The CMS then can take the information and do all other kinds of things like graphical display of data in with graphs, or integrate with search functionality.

So, what do you think? Where should I start? I looked at table of contents for some Plone books but could not find anything close to plugin development.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can't go much wrong with [Aspeli's Professional Plone Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849514429), but if you can get a cheap copy of the [Definitive Guide to Plone](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430218932), that'll do, even if it hasn't been updated for Plone4.

Comment: Thanks Ulrich for your recommendation of the books. I will check them out.

Answer (score 2):

We do this all the time.

Plone is written is Python and can do everything what Python can. Python has gained popularity, on expense of Perl, as UNIX scripting language.

For further ideas, if you need to run long tasks, see [Long running Plone operation with AJAX progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306661/long-running-plone-operation-with-ajax-progress-bar) because you usually don't want to block the page loading for the duration of command-line program run.

Comment: This is definitely a question I will hit on the way :-) Thanks.